# couldn't find Subject without an ID in @subject = Subject.find(params[:subject_id])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a mistake: couldn't find Subject without an ID in @subject = Subject.find(params[:subject_id])
I create many-to-many association. There are three models - teacher, subject and subscription. Subscription model includes following fields: teacher_id and subject_id.

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :teacher, :through => :subscriptions
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :subjects, :through => :subscriptions
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subject
  belongs_to :teacher
end
```

**teacher_controller**

```
def create
        @subject = Subject.find(params[:subject_id])
                @teacher = Teacher.new(teacher_params)
                respond_to do |format|
                  @teacher.subjects << @subject
                  if @teacher.save
        format.html { redirect_to @teacher, notice: 'Teacher was successfully created.' 
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @teacher }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @teacher.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }

      end

    end

    end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
  <%= form_for(@teacher,:html => { class: 'login-form' })  do |f| %>

    <%= f.fields_for :subject do |n| %>
                <%= n.select(@subject, @subjects.map{|p| [p.name, p.id]}) %>
                <% end %>
    ...
<% form %>


resources :teachers do
    resources :subjects
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead

```
def create
  @subject = Subject.where("id =?", params[:subject_id]).first
  unless @subject.blank?
    @teacher = Teacher.new(teacher_params)
    ......
    ......
  else
    # set flash message and redirect
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the view, _form.html.erb, replace the select_tag

```
<%= select_tag "subject_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@subjects, "id", "name") %>
```

And in the controller code,

```
def create
  @subject = Subject.where(id: params[:subject_id]).first

  if @subject.present?
    #YOUR CODE GOES HERE.
  else
    render 'new' # OR render to the action where your teacher form resides
  end
end
```